# fuzzy wuzzy to find a match and other columns associated with match

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, fuzzywuzzy

I have a dataset that I'd like to match on address and then once I have the address match Id like to also know the related unique id associated with it.

Consider this example:

```
df1 =

Address
123 road
abc lane
1 circle
7th avenue 
4 high street


df2=
Address        unique id
123 rd          ID12345
abc lane        ID12346
1 circle        ID12347
7th ave         ID12348
4 high st       ID12349

df3 (result) =
Address           match       unique id
123 road        123 rd           ID12345
abc lane        abc lane         ID12346
1 circle        1 circle         ID12347
7th avenue      7th ave          ID12348
4 high street   4 high st        ID12349
```

So far I've got this for code:

```
address_list = df1['Address'].to_list()
address_search = df2['Address'].to_list()

mat1 = []
for i in address_search:
    mat1.append(process.extract(i,address_list, limit=2))
df1['matches'] = mat1
```

Im able to find the matches and append it to a dataframe, but im not sure how to search for the related unique id column/ row associated with the match found.

Answer (score 1):

- **Update 2.** Match any word in the dataframe #2 rows.

  `str.contains` accepts regular expressions.
  So you can replace spaces with `| (or)` sign and look for any word match in a row.

  Patterns will look like: `123|road`, `7th|avenue` etc. Please, mind that this is a **case sensitive search**.:

  ```
  df2['Address2']=df1['Address'].apply(lambda x: x if df2['Address'].str.contains(x.replace(' ','|')).any() else np.nan)
  ```

**the output:**

[image]

Comment: hey im getting an error saying:
error: unbalanced parenthesis at position 1

Comment: Try to recheck the parenthesis. Or recopy the code. On my PC it works well and gives the result I have attached.